# How Do I Split a Delimited String without creating a function or using the STRING_SPLIT function

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

Need to split a delimited string in the code without using the `STRING_SPLIT` function.

This is in SQL Server 2016 running in compatibility mode 110 (SQL Server 2012), this unfortunately cannot be changed.

```
SELECT
    rsys.Netbios_Name0 As Name,
    (SELECT bg.Name
     FROM vSMS_BoundaryGroup bg
     WHERE bg.GroupID = value) As 'Boundary Group',
    rsys.Full_Domain_Name0 AS Domain
FROM
    v_R_System rsys
INNER JOIN 
    v_GS_BOUNDARYGROUPCACHE bgc ON bgc.ResourceID = rsys.ResourceID
OUTER APPLY 
    STRING_SPLIT(bgc.BoundaryGroupIDs0, ',')
```

I get this error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'

Comment: Please include some sample data, and maybe we can give you a workaround for not being able to use `STRING_SPLIT`.

Comment: Why don't you want to create a function for this? It's the easiest way to solve this and would be the easiest thing to change if you ever could upgrade the compatibility level...

Comment: @stickybit I don't think that's a correct duplicate. splitting to columns will not help the OP on this case.

Comment: @ZoharPeled: Yes, you're right, wrong link.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - valid remark, it is a question of permission, however what would be the best function for this if permission is granted?

Comment: Aaron Bertrand [already did the research on that...](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)

Answer (score 0):

Created the following function:

Using XML
create a table valued function like the below which is using Sql XML feature to split the string.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].StringSplitXML
(
    @String  VARCHAR(MAX), @Separator CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @RESULT TABLE(Value VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN    
 DECLARE @XML XML
 SET @XML = CAST(
    ('<i>' + REPLACE(@String, @Separator, '</i><i>') + '</i>')
    AS XML)

 INSERT INTO @RESULT
 SELECT t.i.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') 
 FROM @XML.nodes('i') AS t(i)
 WHERE t.i.value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') <> ''

 RETURN
END
```

Below example shows how we can use the above function to split the comma delimited string

```
SELECT * 
FROM StringSplitXML('Basavaraj,Kalpana,Shree',',')
```

### With my query

```
SELECT
rsys.Netbios_Name0 As Name
, (SELECT
bg.Name
FROM vSMS_BoundaryGroup bg
WHERE bg.GroupID = value) As 'Boundary Group',
rsys.Full_Domain_Name0 AS Domain
FROM v_R_System rsys
INNER JOIN v_GS_BOUNDARYGROUPCACHE bgc ON bgc.ResourceID = rsys.ResourceID
OUTER APPLY StringSplitXML(bgc.BoundaryGroupIDs0, ',') 
order by rsys.Netbios_Name0
```

---

Thank you
https://sqlhints.com/tag/split-delimited-string-in-sql/